# defining the value for template in helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have created a new helm project and directory structure looks like this as follows:

```
my-app-helm
   /my-app-helm
      /charts
         /payment
            /templates
              _helpers.tpl
              secrets.yaml
              deployment.yaml
              ingress.yaml
              service.yaml
        Chart.yaml
        values.yaml
    Chart.yaml
```

I refer to `template` in many placed like in ingress.yaml:

```
  - host: {{ .Values.payment.apphost }}
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /sft/v1/payment/
        backend:
          serviceName: {{ template "payment.fullname" . }}
          servicePort: 80
```

I have a requirement that my service name, ingress name etc is prefixed with "ccg-helm", therefore I would like to ask how can I ensure value is "ccg-helm" where ever I reference "template":

for example:

serviceName: {{ template "payment.fullname" . }}

resolves to `ccg-helm-payment`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the `payment.fullname` template in `_helpers.tpl` like so:

```
{{/*
Create a default fully qualified app name prefixed with "ccg-helm"
We truncate at 63 chars because some Kubernetes name fields are limited to this (by the DNS naming spec).
If release name contains chart name it will be used as a full name.
*/}}
{{- define "payment.fullname" -}}
{{- if .Values.fullnameOverride }}
{{- .Values.fullnameOverride | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" }}
{{- else }}
{{- $name := default .Chart.Name .Values.nameOverride }}
{{- if contains $name .Release.Name }}
{{- printf "%s-%s" "ccg-helm" .Release.Name | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" }}
{{- else }}
{{- printf "%s-%s-%s" "ccg-helm" .Release.Name $name | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: it works and prefixed with "ccg-helm" but in the end of the resource it also adds "helm" e.g. ccg-helm-payment-helm which I don't want

Answer (score 1):

If your chart was created from the `helm create` command, its [template](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/main/pkg/chartutil/create.go) creates the `"payment.fullname"` template.  The logic there is straightforward:

1. If the `fullnameOverride` value is set, use that as-is, `{{ .Values.fullnameOverride }}`.
2. Let `$name` be the `nameOverride` value, if it's set, otherwise the `name` from `Chart.yaml`.
3. If `$name` is contained in the release name, use `{{ .Release.Name }}`.
4. Otherwise use `{{ .Release.Name }}-{{ $name }}`.

You'll find this in your chart's `_helpers.tpl` file.

So you have two deploy-time options to meet this requirement.  Either set `fullnameOverride` to `ccg-helm`, or use that name as the release name in the `helm install` command.

```sh
helm install . --generate-name --set fullnameOverride=ccg-helm
helm install . ccg-helm
```

For many simpler charts that is the entire name; if you `--set fullnameOverride=ccg-helm` then in your example the Service will be named exactly `ccg-helm`.  If you want it to have some other name then you need to edit both the `service.yaml` and the `ingress.yaml` to have a matching name, usually with some sort of suffix after the template invocation.

Comment: it works and prefixed with "ccg-helm" but in the end of the resource it also adds "helm" e.g. ccg-helm-payment-helm which I don't want